android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.iteratec.tangoApp.MainActivity>
I am building a Flutter app and after adding a new intent-filter to the AndroidManifest, this error emerged:

android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.example.myApp.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

I already added android:exported="true" to the activity which has the intent-filter, but still the same problem arises.
This is the whole MainActivity file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.myApp">

<application
    android:label="myApp"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/myApp">
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" tools:ignore="MissingClass">

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

        <!-- Intent Filter for launching the app -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Intent Filter for App Links -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="my-app.com"
                android:scheme="app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>

<!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
     https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
     https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

     In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent>
</queries>

Any ideas on what can be wrong here?

Can you please share the value of targetSdk and compileSdk in android/app/build.gradle file

compileSdk = 33
I can't find the targetSdkVersion anywhere and I currently can't run the project to find it out that way. Do they need to be the same?

You accidentally added a > at the end of android:label:
android:label="@string/myApp">

Remove it and everything should be fine:
android:label="@string/myApp"


Sometimes it's the little things in life...
